# Removing carriage returns from database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am so confused. I used the following query to get rid of unwanted returns in the data. It worked fine for all the fields except "first_name". Instead it changed all the first_name fields to "0". There is no difference between the first_name replace and the rest, right? I don't understand what happened!

```
UPDATE donors
    SET 
        `first_name` = Replace(Replace(`first_name`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
    AND
        `last_name` = Replace(Replace(`last_name`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
    AND
        `address_1` = Replace(Replace(`address_1`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
    AND
        `city` = Replace(Replace(`city`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
    AND
        `zipcode` = Replace(Replace(`zipcode`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

I am using MYSQL, and this is the only query I used. The change happened when I executed it. I copy and pasted it here.

Here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `donors` (
  `donor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` text NOT NULL,
  `last_name` text NOT NULL,
  `company` text NOT NULL,
  `donor_notes` text NOT NULL,
  `email_1` text NOT NULL,
  `email_2` text NOT NULL,
  `phone_1` text NOT NULL,
  `phone_2` text NOT NULL,
  `fax` text NOT NULL,
  `address_1` text NOT NULL,
  `address_2` text NOT NULL,
  `city` text NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `salt` text NOT NULL,
  `newsletter` text NOT NULL,
  `address_id` text NOT NULL,
  `ip` text NOT NULL,
  `status` text NOT NULL,
  `approved` text NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`donor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=445 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What database are you using? In MSSQL, you should use commas instead of those `AND`. As you are updating the table onto itself, it might have happened that you previously tried some wrong query which produced what you explain, but it's not the query you are trying right now. Did you first try doing a `SELECT` with your replacements instead?

Comment: could you share the table's DDL?

Comment: Please edit your question to correct your tagging (to identify which database you're using), as well as showing the table schema, some sample data, and before/after table contents (at least a small snippet of a few lines).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, I think the problem are all those `AND`. In MySql, between each updated field you should insert a comma, not an `AND`, which is used for conditions.

So when you ran this:

```
UPDATE donors
SET 
    `first_name` = Replace(Replace(`first_name`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
AND
    `last_name` = Replace(Replace(`last_name`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
....
```

What you actually did was:

```
UPDATE donors
SET 
    `first_name` = some_varchar AND condition AND condition AND condition AND condition
```

Each one of these conditions was comparing each column to itself after doing the replacements. Just being one of those false, the result was 0. And that's why that value was stored in your column.

Your script should have been like this:

```
UPDATE donors
SET 
    `first_name` = Replace(Replace(`first_name`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),
    `last_name` = Replace(Replace(`last_name`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),
    `address_1` = Replace(Replace(`address_1`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),
    `city` = Replace(Replace(`city`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''),
    `zipcode` = Replace(Replace(`zipcode`, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

References:

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

By the way, all those `` ` `` are not necessary, you only need them when the column has spaces or is a reserved keyword.